# NestJS Application, `Cannot find module "express"` when installing dependencies in production mode with pnpm

Tags: express, nestjs, yarnpkg, pnpm

The dependencies in my `package.json` file look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@golevelup/nestjs-graphql-request": "0.1.14",
    "@nestjs/axios": "3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/config": "3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "7.0.3",
    "axios": "1.4.0",
    "class-transformer": "0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "0.14.0",
    "discord-interactions": "3.4.0",
    "graphql-request": "6.1.0",
    "helmet": "7.0.0",
    "joi": "17.9.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "swagger-ui-express": "4.6.3"
  },
```

If I install all dependencies using `pnpm`, 8.6.5 and run the app with `"start:dev": "nest start --watch",` - everything works fine.

However if I:

1. Install all dependencies (to have `nest cli`)
2. Make a build with `nest build`
3. Install only production dependencies with `pnpm i -P`
4. Run the app with `node ./dist/src/main.js`

I get an error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'express'`

If I perform a similar process with `yarn`, 1.22.19 (steps 1-4), everything works fine

=== Update ===

Tried to change the config for peer dependencies - the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is [somewhat answered on NestJS GH](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/10829#issuecomment-1374906734)

It is a good idea to prohibit usage of extraneous dependencies with [the eslint plugin](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md)